# why does bridge sql developer command fail when using count

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Sql developer  19.2.1.247

when I run the following stament

```
    BRIDGE BRTOOTHERENV AS OTHERENVCONNECTION( select *  from my_table where rownum = 1 )
select * from BRTOOTHERENV;
```

the command brings results without any problem, but if I try to get the count of the table with

```
BRIDGE BRTOOTHERENV AS OTHERENVCONNECTION( select count(*)  from my_table )
select * from BRTOOTHERENV;
```

the command fails with

**ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"**

what could be happening ?